# Is there any distributed, strict, transactional, read/write L2 cache provider for hibernate in weblogic 10 + java 5?

Tags: hibernate, caching, distributed, transactional, strict

Is there any distributed, strict, transactional, read/write L2 cache provider for hibernate in weblogic 10 + java 5?

Infinispan looks appealing, but you need java 6.  Hands are tied with java 5.